# Where can I find the Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging.dll?

Tags: c#, debugging, ironpython, scripting-language

since version 2.7, the Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging.dll is not shipped with IronPython any more.
Where can I find it - or is there an alternative if I want to implement single stepping for IronPython?
All example implementations that I found are from 2010 or older, using the IronPython version with included Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging.dll.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it moved into the core with the rest of the DLR, it's no longer special to IronPython. But I came across this question while looking for info on debugging so I may be completely wrong.